# Mapping a List<OfType> to a EF list<OfType> with LINQ?

Tags: c#

Not sure how to Approach this correctly, My current approach is just far to untidy and just a bad approach in general I feel.

> How do I Map ListA(qeustions) to ListB(qeustionSet) using Linq

They both are of the same type the Object Names are the same the Values just change.

```
  Qeustions qeustionSet = new Qeustions() ;
     foreach (var item in qeustions)
     {

                _context.Qeustions.Add(qeustionSet);
                qeustionSet.FrontEndDevelopment = item.FrontEndDevelopment;
                qeustionSet.ArchitectureDesignAndPlanning = item.ArchitectureDesignAndPlanning;
                qeustionSet.InternalMeetings = item.InternalMeetings;
                qeustionSet.ClientMeetings = item.ClientMeetings;

    }
```

```
public partial class Qeustions
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Respondent { get; set; }
        public int? InternalMeetings { get; set; }
        public int? ClientMeetings { get; set; }
        public int? EmailsPhoneSkypeCalls { get; set; }
        public int? Research { get; set; }
        public int? DbDesign { get; set; }
        public int? ArchitectureDesignAndPlanning { get; set; }
        public int? BackEndDevelopment { get; set; }
        public int? FrontEndDevelopment { get; set; }
        public int? Integration { get; set; }
        public int? Testing { get; set; }

        public virtual Respondents IdNavigation { get; set; }
    }
```

The issue being:

Compiler Error CS1503 **Argument 'number' cannot convert from TypeA to TypeB or System.Collection.Generic.List to Qeustions**  Thus the reason for the map

Comment: You mean like `.Select()`? Or in a more "automatic" way like [automapper](https://automapper.org/)?

Comment: The Data will change on a Submission so if I can select the data from A -> B that is fine otherwise Automapping is probably my solutions. Its just EF expects a list of TypeA but my list comes in as systems Generic so I have to map it(or so I believe)

Comment: .Select method will be helpful